# How to convert unique variable with alphas to a unique variable with only integers?

Tags: php

Our product's unique identifiers have SKUs with alphas like this: "A4-DGH-D4-WT-LT10".  We need to integrate with a platform that only accepts integer unique identifiers.  I was thinking to hash our SKU variable, but this still will create a variable with alphas.  Is it possible to hash my unique identifier into only integers?  If not hash, is there another method within PHP that can be used?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Any length limitation?

Comment: I just found crc32.  I think this will work just fine.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.crc32.php

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think crc32 will work.  I don't need a hash.  After further consideration, I need to convert my SKU to an integer temporarily, and then also be able to convert it back from the integer later on.

Comment: I mean must the integer limit in 32bits or any length?

Comment: full alphabet SKUs = A-Z 0-9 ?

Comment: Yes, and with the hyphens.  I think I need something like this instead...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54702861/how-to-convert-unique-variable-with-alphas-to-a-unique-variable-with-only-intege

Comment: Hyphens have permanent position?

Comment: Can't you just build a mapping between SKU and numeric values, by incrementing a variable for each new SKU ? That can easily be stored in a database, a file, ...

Comment: What if you just removed the `-`, and then converted this from Base36 to Base10? `base_convert(str_replace('-', '', 'A4-DGH-D4-WT-LT10'), 36, 10)` will get you `47959504205907098864` If the `-` are always in constant places, I think that should get you unique values, right? (If you could have `A4-DGH[…]` and `A4D-GH[…]` as two different SKUs in your system, then this would obviously not work.)